# SQLSTATE[HY000] [2003] Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (13)

Tags: mysql, linux, symfony, permissions

Getting the following error when I try to log into my Symfony application on a new CentOs server:

> SQLSTATE[HY000] [2003] Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (13)

Stranger yet, I can run the doctrine:schema:update command which works so I know the credentials are correct in parameters.yml.

This is my current my.cnf:

```
[mysqld]
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
user=mysql
# Disabling symbolic-links is recommended to prevent assorted security risks
symbolic-links=0

[mysqld_safe]
log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid

#bind-address = 127.0.0.1
```

I also tried disabling IP tables and had the same result.

Here is my hosts file:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6
```

Any ideas?

Comment: refer this link: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/can-not-connect-to-server.html

Answer (score 1):

Physically deleting my app/cache folder and then warming the cache again fixed this problem. I tried the cache:clear command before this and it didn't work.